# Swift, How to make storyboard less heavy?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Suddenly, Xcode can not build my app, it take very long and make my computer stuck.

I was looking for the cause and I saw that my storyboard is 1,50 GB heavy, and when I try to run it take something like 7 GB of my ram (I have just 6-7 controller in project, so strange!)

How can I make it more light?

What can I delete in my Xcode?

Comment: you should show us your xcode

Comment: multiple storyboards, you can use storyboard references, you can move custom views to separate xibs. I have a project with about 200 controllers and I use the cheapest apple laptop that exists and I have no problems. It's also possible you have a bug in some designable.

Comment: Definitely split them up (though if there's only 6-7 controllers, this doesn't feel necessary). Xcode includes a "Editor>Refactor to Storyboard…" tool that will extract selected scenes into another storyboard automatically. But I've never seen a 1.5G storyboard before (one of my most storyboard-heavy projects has a total of 4M across 45 files). I'm a little suspicious of why it's that large. Once you start splitting it up, definitely see which one is contributing so much. How are you determining its size?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to delete your project.xcworkspace and reset your simulator. If you make multiplies storyboard it will be always heavy and hard to build

Answer (score 0):

You could use multiples storyboards instead of storage everything on 1 
send the user with prepare forSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Load View") {
        // pass data to next view
    }
}
```